# Make child fully contained inside parent and child invisible when not fitting?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to make a frame in basic html/css and I'd like to insert within that frame an horizontal div for me to scroll through (horizontally). Note that I don't and won't be using anything other than pure CSS and pure HTML, as anything else (jQuery included) is banned for this little project

So far here's what I have:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.frame {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  width: 40%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: auto;
}

.frame .caroussel {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.51);
  width: 300%;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="frame">
    <div class="caroussel"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="frame">
    <div class="caroussel"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's what it looks like [right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXG8i.jpg)

And here's how I'd like it to [look whilst allowing me to scroll horizontally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og0Va.jpg)

Comment: refer to [this article](https://css-tricks.com/pure-css-horizontal-scrolling/), the demo [here](https://codepen.io/pieter-biesemans/pen/BQBWXX) should work for you

Comment: your code doesn't show anything in the snippet. are you sure that's all the code? also, you have two frames, so do you want to scroll div in each frame?